# How to write robots.txt code to stop indexing the few webpages

Tags: robots.txt

I just want to remove some pages of my website from indexing. Like when I add case studies or blogs, I don't want to index all the blogs on my website https://snapvisibility.com/.

Here is my existing robots code
'''User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/'''

Answer (score 0):

You can disallow just a specific file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /post-samples-url1
Disallow: /post-samples-url2
Disallow: /post-samples-url3
Disallow: /post-samples-url4
```